# Changing the x-axis of the binom.density.plot in binom package in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm preparing some materials to show differences between Bayesian Credible Intervals and Frequentist Confidence Intervals, and wanted to visually show how how BCIs can be interpreted in cases where 0% of cases satisfy a particular condition:

```
library(binom)
temp <- binom.bayes(0, 100)
binom.bayes.densityplot(temp)
```

[!Result of binom.bayes.densityplot[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TbnQ.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TbnQ.jpg)

I'd like to change the x-axis so that it is more visually apparent where the interval ends, but I"m having trouble with figuring out how to "hack" in the `binom` package to change the x-axis. The package's documentation indicates that it uses the `ggplot2` package to create the chart.

Comment: Are you suggesting there are no "frequentist" confidence intervals when zero events occur?

Comment: have you used `axis(side=1,...)`?

Comment: @BondedDust  I'm not sure how you interpreted that from my question, but in my example, I'm pointing out that the calculations we use would indicate that the Frequentist CI is equal to 0%.

Comment: A zero width CI for a point observation of 0 is not what is traditionally quoted in the frequentist literature. There is an extensive literature on this. Search on "exact methods" and "The Rule of Three".

Comment: @MichaelChirico Do you mean `binom.bayes.densityplot(temp) + axis(side = 1,...)` ?

Comment: @BondedDust Thanks for the clarification, I'll use that into my example. What if the % is near 0%?

Comment: There are exact methods for small numbers as well as for zeros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
binom.bayes.densityplot(temp) + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 0.05))
```

[image]

The more common `xlim()` doesn't work here, as that will exclude the points outside of the plotting window, causing the drawing of the polygon to fail.

Comment: Thank you!! Don't have the reputation to upvote, but I appreciate this.